# TYPO3 files in impexp

Tags: typo3

When I export a t3d from one system (TYPO3 6.2) and import it in a second system (TYPO3 8.7) the content images changes. I've expected the image is also transferred from one system to the other, but TYPO3 seems to just say "the imported content element has sys_file with UID 123, so I still use this file", but this UID references to a totally dfferent image in the second TYPO3 system.

Comment: Problem is, the images are missing in the export. There's a bug report for it: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/82047

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images from standard content elements are not exported, if option „[ALL tables]“ or options „sys_file*“ are choosed for „Use static relations for tables“. Don’t select these options and your export will contain the images.

Also see [forge.typo3.org/issues/82047](http://forge.typo3.org/issues/82047). Thanks to Christian Kuhn for working this out.